# Replace full types by type aliases in Scaladoc

Tags: scala, scaladoc

I have a trait with 4 type parameters: `Decoder[E, D, F, T`] (where `E` describes the encoded type, `D` the decoded type, `F` the failure type and `T` is a phantom type used to tag decoder instances).

Each project that defines custom `Decoder` instances also defines a type alias for them. For example: `CellDecoder[Int]` is a type alias for `Decoder[String, Int, DecodeError, csv.type]`.

There's an additional trait, `DecoderCompanion[E, F, T]`, which defines useful methods for a custom `Decoder` instance's companion object. So, for example, the `CellDecoder` companion object would extend `DecoderCompanion[String, DecodeError, csv.type]`.

To have a concrete example, here's what this might look like:

```
trait DecoderCompanion[E, F, T] {
  def apply[F](implicit dec: Decoder[E, D, F, T]): Decoder[E, D, F, T] = dec
}

object CellDecoder extends DecoderCompanion[String, DecodeResult, csv.type]
```

When generating the API doc for `CellDecoder`, scaladoc will not figure out that it should replace all instances of `Decoder[String, D, DecodeResult, csv.type]` by `CellDecoder[D]`. Readers would expect `CellDecoder.apply` to yield a `CellDecoder`, not a `Decoder` - a type they might not even be aware exists.

I understand why, or at least why this wouldn't be the default behaviour. I was wondering whether there was a way, either as a scaladoc flag or type level trickery, to change that behaviour?

Answer (score 3):

There is--but you may not like it :-)

It involves using the infamous Scaladoc 'use case' feature. For example, see the [List#mapConserve](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.List@mapConserve(f:A=>A):List[A]) method and its [source documentation](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.11.8/src/library/scala/collection/immutable/List.scala#L150). Notice the `@usecase` tag? That's what's telling Scaladoc to show the given 'use case' type in the main overview, and hide the actual type in the 'Full Signature' area.

Comment: I'd thought of that, actually, but couldn't find a way to make it work without having to redefine the methods I'm inheriting for the sole purpose of documentation, which I felt was a bit much. Did I miss something?

Comment: @NicolasRinaudo you probably didn't. The only thing I can think of is to define `CellDecoder.apply` and just call out to `super.apply` in the implementation. This shouldn't be too onerous because you just have to do it for a few decoder companion objects, right?

Comment: right, but the problem is that my example is simplified, I have quite a bit more than just the one method :)

Comment: @NicolasRinaudo OK, in that case I would talk to the Scaladoc folks and see if they have something up their sleeves.